# Function of "Refresh" in windows

Tags: windows

What is the function of refresh in Windows ?
is it just to redraw the screen ?

Comment: i added the bogust first line, lese SO was not allowing to post this question.

Comment: What’s a “bogus line”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most common cases:

1. In Windows Explorer, re-read the current folder (updates file information)
2. In Internet Explorer (and most browsers), reloads the current page

The <kbd>F5</kbd> key is most commonly used for this function. In most browsers, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> forces a full page reload, ignoring any cached files.

Answer (score 2):

It can just redraw the screen, or it can reload a page, like in a browser...it depends on where you hit it. It is worth noting that with some web sites, you need to hit `CTRL+F5` to refresh the cache and refresh the page.